# How to print string in the first and last TWO line to multiple textfile in python

Tags: python

I'm still new in python. I need help about some logic here..

this is the code so far..

```
from itertools import chain
filename = 'D:/Workspace/Python/textfile.txt'
with open(filename, 'rb') as inf:
    header = next(inf)
    for index, line in enumerate(inf,start=1):
        with open('D:/Workspace/Python/textfile{}.txt'.format(index) ,'w') as outf:
            outf.write('Path : %s\n' %outf.name)
            outf.write(header)
            for line in chain([line], inf):
                if 'string' in line:
                    header = line
                    break
                outf.write(line)

    for idx in range(1, index):
        filename = 'D:/Workspace/Python/textfile{}.txt'.format(idx)
        with open(filename, 'a') as outf:
            outf.write(line)
```

I have textfile.txt path on D:/Workspace/Python/textfile.txt. Have string like this

```
date : day - month - year

string1
i have pen
i have book
string2
i have ruler
i have bag
string3
....

this is the list of item i have in string

author : stevanus
```

then print to..

in the textfile1.txt

```
path : D:/Workspace/savedfile/textfile1.txt

date : day - month - year <-- print this

string1
i have pen
i have book

this is the list of item i have in string1 <--print this but in string1

author : stevanus
```

in the textfile2.txt

```
path : D:/Workspace/savedfile/textfile2.txt

date : day - month - year <-- print this again

string2
i have ruler
i have bag

this is the list of item i have in string2 <-- and print this again but in string2

author : stevanus
```

so on with other string..

Sorry for my bad english. Hope it's clear

Comment: So what does your code do instead? What have *you tried* to implement this, and how precisely did it fail to work?

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to achieve the whole thing at once.  Instead, structure your requirements and thoughts a bit before coding.

It seems that you have a file in a custom format.  Let's formulate the rules for this format first:

- Your format is line-based.
- The first line is a "header", containing a date.
- Then there is an empty line -- or multiple ones?
- Then there are multiple sections, where each one starts with an identifier "stringX" and multiple lines of content.  Are empty lines allowed here?
- Then again, one (or more?) empty lines
- Finally, there is a footer.

Did you notice the questions?  Address these first.

Now you seem to want to generate new files, one per section in the source file.  Each file shall have the header and footer of the source file, while the section identifier is to be inserted into the footer.

I would suggest you first try to *write a function* that reads the source file, identifying the header, sections and footer:

```
header, sections, footer = read_source_file(file_path)
```

When you have this, the code for the output files will be pretty easy. When `sections` is a list of pairs `(identifier, content)`, the code might look like this:

```
for identifier, content in sections:
    with open(...) as file:
        # Write header...
        # Write content lines...
        # Write footer, replacing "string" with identifier
```

While developing `read_source_file`, you can try out and debug your function in the interactive prompt, until it does what you want.